# LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _D3DXCreateFontA@48

Tags: c++, direct3d

After looking at this problem I just don't see what I have done wrong. I have made multiple projects to see if that would change but nothing so far. I have also taken out the portion I have added and now it will compile and create the dll.

Drawing.h

```
pragma once

#include <Windows.h>
#include <d3d9.h>
#include <d3dx9.h>

LPD3DXFONT m_font = NULL;

void text_Draw(LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 pDevice, int x, int y, DWORD color, const CHAR *text)
{
    RECT rect;
    SetRect(&rect, x, y, x + 100, y);
    m_font->DrawTextA(NULL, text, -1, &rect, DT_CENTER | DT_NOCLIP, color);
}
```

The error :

> LNK2019   unresolved external symbol _D3DXCreateFontA@48 referenced in function "long __stdcall Hooked_EndScene(struct IDirect3DDevice9 *)" (?Hooked_EndScene@@YGJPAUIDirect3DDevice9@@@Z)    dx_Hookv3

Comment: Where is `m_font` initialized?

Answer (score 0):

`D3DXCreateFont` is a function in the legacy deprecated `D3DX9` utility library. The import library is `d3dx9.lib` which only ships in the legacy DirectX SDK. The Direct3D 9 import library `d3d9.lib` is in the Windows SDK. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx).

> Note that the `D3DX9` utility library DLL is *not* part of the operating system. It is only installed by using the legacy DirectX End-user Runtime Redistribution Package. Direct3D 9.0c itself is part of every version of Windows since Windows XP SP2. See [Not So Direct Setup](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2010/09/08/not-so-direct-setup/)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah if you didn't initalized `m_font` anywhere before using it will cause the error you are getting. Here is a link for Classes if you have forgotten how to use them. http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/

```
pragma once

#include <Windows.h>
#include <d3d9.h>
#include <d3dx9.h>

LPD3DXFONT m_font = NULL;
m_font myFont;
void text_Draw(LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 pDevice, int x, int y, DWORD color, const CHAR *text)
{
    RECT rect;
    SetRect(&rect, x, y, x + 100, y);
    m_font->DrawTextA(NULL, text, -1, &rect, DT_CENTER | DT_NOCLIP, color);
}
```